# ColdFusion Installation with Apache web server

Tags: apache, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I had a good experience configuring ColdFusion applications using IIS Web server but my client is asking me to configure the applications using Apache. I found few links where in I did not get the exact required information. My Question is is there any official path to download the Apache. If yes can any one share the path. How do I go after downloading the Apache web server. Does any one have step by step process to configure the Apache in ColdFusion.

By the way I am using ColdFusion 11 enterprise edition. We had multiple instances related to this ColdFusion 11. I had a option to select Apache when going to WSConfig file. But I am not exactly sure if I need to download the software before doing this process.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [ColdFusion 11 Support Matrix](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/coldfusion/pdfs/cf11/coldfusion11-support-matrix.pdf), Apache 2.2.26 and 2.4 are supported. You can download Apache 2.4 from [here](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache24).

You can refer to [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html) document, for how to install, configure and run Apache 2.4 under Microsoft Windows.

And lastly, you can refer to [ColdFusion 11 Installation guide](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/download/attachments/142314172/ColdFusion11_Installing.pdf) for installing and configuring CF11 with Apache.

Comment: Important to notice: `The Apache HTTP Server Project itself does not provide binary releases of software, only source code.` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html Where best to get apache from; valid question! Maybe: http://www.apachelounge.com/download/